# Can I "save" Graphics2D drawn image that will not be affected with consequent usage of DstOut composite?

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I am making my own UI design based on swing JFrame.
The button element I made is using DstOut AlphaComposite to "engrave" text on white fill while mouse is holding button. It fills button area with white and then paints button text with DstOut to make the background visible through area where text is engraved. To make this, I create an instance of BufferedImage where I paint the button and then engrave the text. After the image is done, I paint it in the place where the button should be.

[Normal and holding appearances of button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fY1N.png)
**The question I have is, can I do this manipulation without creating a separate BufferedImage object?**

The aforementioned method has a disadvantage for me — all Graphics settings are reset. Anti-aliasing is a simple thing to set again, but I am also planning to use scale and translate to animate scene transitions.

If I use g.scale(4, 4) before drawing the entire window, everything becomes 4 times bigger, but that BufferedImage still treats 1 pixel as 1 pixel, not knowing that it's going to be upscaled. The upscaling is done when BufferedImage is drawn on the screen, but not when BufferedImage's contents are drawn. This makes the upscaled picture look bad as a result of upscaling low-res picture (each pixel now takes area of 16 pixels).

[Upscale example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7Ygu.png) As you can see on the screenshot, the first button with usual appearance looks good, but the second one which uses a BufferedImage to draw its border (in extended animated state) looks terrible.

A perfect solution for me would be some way to prevent AlphaComposite.DstOut touching anything drawn before starting drawing of the button **but** to do it using the same Graphics2D instance to keep settings which include scale and translation.

If it's impossible, can you please recommend a way of getting the same result but better than just adding translation and scale to paint method arguments and tediously processing it?

Comment: It's a little hard to say without more context - in theory, you don't need the buffered image, simple apply the `AlphaComposite`, do you rendering and reset the composite when your done on the instance of `Graphics` you have - but's in a while since I've done anything like this and most of the previous experience was with doing it multiple images

Comment: I first paint background picture, then all the elements consequently. If I use DstOut composite to clean pixels (by applying color with 0 alpha) it also clears the background (and makes window transparent BTW) which is unwanted for me.

Comment: Or did you mean that I should paint the background picture, create a transparent BufferedImage for all the elements to be painted on and only then paint it in the window? That actually sounds reasonable, I'll try it out.